# AWS Lambda API issue "Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 129"

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have developed API in AWS using Lambda NodeJS. It working as per requirement with correct response but periodically it's giving below error.

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
    "errorMessage": "RequestId: 3401bb1f-eb50-4c39-87cd-ce1188ce9150 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 129"
}
```

Above error only occurs when I used MySQL database connection with SQL operation in code.

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this by installing npm package "npm i serverless-mysql" instead of "npm i mysql" and updated the code as per need.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when i uploaded an incorrect json file to my `S3`; When i ran the URL from API gateway, i got this error but no real hints;

When i tested the Lambda function, i got the specific place of issue in the JSON file on the Execution Results section of the Lambda Management Console.

Documenting this here to help someone in the future.

Comment: Same here.  I got a vague error `RuntimeError: Runtime unable to report state` in my IDE.  But logging into AWS Lambda, I could see it was a permissions issue ( related to `lambda:InvokeFunction` )

Answer (score 1):

This error could be because of running out of connections at MySQL connection pool. You need to reuse the connection while making subsequent lambda calls. The connection need to be closed at the end of lambda lifecycle.

Comment: var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({DATABASE_CONNECTION_HERE});
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
      var result;
      var sql = 'MYSQL_QUERY_HERE';
        connection.query({
          sql : sql
      }, function (error, rows, fields) {
          if (error) {
                connection.destroy();
                throw error;
          } else {
           callback(error, result);
           connection.end(function (err) { callback(err, result);});
          } 
      });
};